# How do I get the current Avg. CPC bid for a keyword in Google AdWords API using R (preferably) or Python?

Tags: python, r, google-ads-api

So I'm a bit stuck. I want to extract the Avg CPC and Max CPC bid for a list of keywords from the Adwords API using R . If it's hard python works as well :) .

I've tried using RAdwords, but I couldn't find the correct report type in the list from adwords https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports

So does anyone have any experience with this. For easy info I'm attaching a picture from the adwords interface where the measurements are easily visible.[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the **RAdwords** package you can query the Adwords/Google Ads API and download all the statistics of your keywords. The corresponding report type is the `KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`. Please note in the Adwords API documentation that `criteria` relates to the keyword text within this report type.

```
# Authentication
library(RAdwords)
google_auth <- doAuth()
# Create the statement
body <- statement(select = c('Criteria', 'AverageCpc', 'CpcBid'),
                  report = "KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT",
                  start = "2018-01-01",
                  end = "2018-01-10")
# Query the Google Ads API
# Make sure to use the Adwords Account Id (MCC Id will not work)
data <- getData(clientCustomerId = 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
                google_auth = google_auth,
                statement = body)
```